# Counting unique addresses in a list based on criteria in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of a few hundred addresses and have a day of the week matched with those days.  I need to know how many of the weekdays have a unique address associated with it.

For this example, Monday has 4 addresses but only 2 of them are unique:

[image]